# Dealing with seemingly undocumented error code from Azure Blob Storage batch operations: TlsVersionNotPermitted

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I've been dealing with some very strange behavior using the Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch NuGet package. When trying to perform a batch delete operation, the request fails with a TlsVersionNotPermitted error code.

Azure actually provides a list of possible error codes that Blob Storage can return here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes
but this error code is nowhere to be found in the list. A google search for "TlsVersionNotPermitted" literally yields no results, so I am pretty confused about how and why this error occurs.

If anyone has any knowledge about what could cause this I'm very interested in hearing about it.
Everything works fine with the non-batch operations by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a pretty self-documenting error code - the version of TLS the package is using is no longer allowed by Azure. If you are not on the latest version of the package, update; if you are, [file an issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :(

Comment: Does it work if you execute this code at some point before trying your blob operation? `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: @Crowcoder unfortunately not. We seem to be running the latest version, so I might have a go at opening an issue on the github repo as ian-kemp suggested. Thanks for taking the time to answer guys!

Comment: @sunero4 I'm having exactly the same issue. Have you opened an issue on GitHub or already found a solution?

Comment: @NelsonReis Thanks for reminding me! I actually forgot about this because we decided at work to just go with a non-batch implementation for now. I have created an issue on their github now: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13524
If you have any additional information feel free to comment there :)